# check if name is same with name in email

Tags: r

I want to validate name with name in email, i am trying below solutions but not working for me .
objective is to check if name are exactly same with name in email, name can be separated by (space, comma, dots) thats why i am using separator.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Nic Hawk","tt dy","anz kpw p","timm ral","Karen Mulc","lew wey","sun mark"),
                 email = c("Nic.Hawk@tttt.com",   "tt.dy@aquan@tttt.com", "anz.kpw.p@tttt.com",   "frez.tal@tttt.com",    "Karen.Mulc@tttt.com",   "lew.wey@tttt.com", "wall.kit@tttt.com"))


Name= "name"
Email="email"
separator = " "

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Name_match = map2_int(str_extract_all(Name, "\\w+"), 
                               str_extract_all(str_remove(Email, "\\@.*"), "\\w+"),
                               ~ +(!all(str_detect(.y, str_c(.x, collapse=" "))))))

df <- df %>%
  separate(Name,
           into = c("last_name", "first_name"),
           sep = separator,
           remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(first_name = tolower(first_name),
         last_name = tolower(last_name)) %>%
  mutate(name_email_match = 0L*str_detect(Email,
                                          paste0("^", first_name, separator, last_name,
                                                 "@\\w+\\.com$"))) %>%
  select(-c(first_name, last_name))
```

the output should be mutated column with 1 and 0 (1 for True(matched), 0 for false (Not matching))

Comment: I remember I saw a question similar to this one from you already... I think you don't have it quite clear how to use variable names in dplyr. You don't need to create the variables Name and Email. just write `name` and `email` as it is inside your dplyr statements :-) [even if that doesn't solve your problem it will increase the quality of your code]

Comment: actually sometimes data have different names of column name and email so i have given a input parameters for name and email according names in data.

Comment: Then you're using it wrong. You need to write it this way: `!!sym(Name)`. My advise it to rename them at the beginning, so you don't have to write `!!sym` every time.

Comment: ok will update that, but my codes are not working

Comment: Name ="name" ;
Name = !!sym(Name)   like this way ...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

Name  <- "name"
Email <- "email"
separator <- " "

df %>%
 
 # everything to lower
 mutate(across(all_of(c(Name, Email)), tolower)) %>% 
 
 # extract interesting part from email
 mutate(email_name = str_extract(!!sym(Email), "([a-z.]+)(?=@.+)")) %>% 
 
 # replace . with separator
 mutate(email_name = str_replace_all(email_name, "\\.", separator)) %>% 
 
 # compare
 mutate(name_email_match = +(!!sym(Name) == email_name))

#>         name                email email_name name_email_match
#> 1   nic hawk    nic.hawk@tttt.com   nic hawk                1
#> 2      tt dy tt.dy@aquan@tttt.com      tt dy                1
#> 3  anz kpw p   anz.kpw.p@tttt.com  anz kpw p                1
#> 4   timm ral    frez.tal@tttt.com   frez tal                0
#> 5 karen mulc  karen.mulc@tttt.com karen mulc                1
#> 6    lew wey     lew.wey@tttt.com    lew wey                1
#> 7   sun mark    wall.kit@tttt.com   wall kit                0
```

---

Related to my comment, if you want to rename it so that you don't have to use `!!sym(...)` every time, you can go:

```
df %>%
 rename(Name  = !!sym(Name),
        Email = !!sym(Email)) %>%
 
 # everything to lower
 mutate(across(c(Name, Email), tolower)) %>% 

 # compare
 mutate(name_email_match = +(str_replace_all(Name, separator, "\\.") == 
                              str_extract(Email, "([a-z.]+)(?=@.+)")))

#>         Name                Email name_email_match
#> 1   nic hawk    nic.hawk@tttt.com                1
#> 2      tt dy tt.dy@aquan@tttt.com                1
#> 3  anz kpw p   anz.kpw.p@tttt.com                1
#> 4   timm ral    frez.tal@tttt.com                0
#> 5 karen mulc  karen.mulc@tttt.com                1
#> 6    lew wey     lew.wey@tttt.com                1
#> 7   sun mark    wall.kit@tttt.com                0
```

Comment: how can i ignore Na and blank cells, if column name or email is blanks or NA

Comment: There are a few ways.. you can `filter` them out before for example (check out `?dplyr::filter`)

Comment: if i filter out those then it will also impact the original data .that i dont want

Comment: In this moment, if you have NAs in the data, simply you will get some NAs on `name_email_match`. You can fill them out with zeros. For example with `%>% tidyr::replace_na(list(name_email_match = 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(name1 = str_remove_all(name, '\\s'), email1 = str_remove(str_remove_all(str_extract(email, '.*(?=@.*)'), '[\\.\\s]' ), '@.*')) %>% 
   mutate(op = +(str_detect(name1, email1))) %>% select(-c(name1, email1))
        name                email op
1   Nic Hawk    Nic.Hawk@tttt.com  1
2      tt dy tt.dy@aquan@tttt.com  1
3  anz kpw p   anz.kpw.p@tttt.com  1
4   timm ral    frez.tal@tttt.com  0
5 Karen Mulc  Karen.Mulc@tttt.com  1
6    lew wey     lew.wey@tttt.com  1
7   sun mark    wall.kit@tttt.com  0
```